# Changing parent css on child hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have look around this forum a lot and can only find the opposite to my question, in other words i am looking to find how to change the parent div's background when the child div is hovered over, i can only find how to change the child div, when the parent is hovered over.

I have 1 parent div with an inner submit button:

```html
<div class="ugd_ele_normal_base">
  <input name="ugd_1" type="submit" class="ugd_ele_normal"/>
</div><!--end ugd_ele_normal_base-->
```

What i want is for when the submit button is hovered over, the parent css changes background.

I have tried a few things, but nothing seems to work.

Thanks for the help

Comment: http://reference.sitepoint.com/javascript/Node/parentNode

Comment: With CSS4 you'll be able to do `.ugd_ele_normal_base! > .ugd_ele_normal:hover { background: red; }`, but that doesn't really help you right now. So I won't even bring it up.

Comment: CSS4 wtf? Wonder if we will even be alive by the times it becomes implemented :3

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would use jQuery & CSS for this:

CSS

```
.black {
     background-color: #000000;
}
```

jQuery

```
$(function() {
   $('.ugd_ele_normal').hover( function(){
      $(this).parent().addClass("black");
   },
   function(){
      $(this).parent().removeClass("black");
   });
});
```

Comment: +1 It's always a good idea to store styling states in CSS rather than your JS. Separation of concerns, maintainability, etc.

Answer (score 5):

```
$('input.ugd_ele_normal').on({
    mouseenter: function() {
        $(this).parent().css('background', 'url(/folder/image1.jpg)');
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
        $(this).parent().css('background', 'url(/folder/image2.jpg)');
    }
});
```

or short(er) version:

```
$('input.ugd_ele_normal').on('mouseenter mouseleave', function(e) {
     $(this).parent()
            .css('background-color', e.type=='mouseenter'?'url(/folder/image1.jpg)':'url(/folder/image2.jpg)');
});
```

and to retrieve the old image:

```
var bgImg = $('input.ugd_ele_normal').css('background-image'),
    hvImg = 'url(/folder/image2.jpg)';

$('input.ugd_ele_normal').on('mouseenter mouseleave', function(e) {
     $(this).parent()
            .css('background-image', e.type=='mouseenter'?hvImg:bgImg);
});
```

or use classes:

```
.hoverClass {background: url(/folder/image2.jpg);}
```

-

```
$('input.ugd_ele_normal').on('mouseenter mouseleave', function() {
   $(this).toggleClass('hoverClass');
});
```

Comment: Thankyou very much for your answer it is working great, the only thing is, i am actually dealing with images, so how would i do it if i was switching between 2 images? rather than colours

Answer (score 2):

You can do this way.

```
$("#ugd_1").hover(function(){
   $(this).parent().css("background","red");
},
 function(){
      $(this).parent().css("background","none");
 });
```

​
    ​
Live Demo :

http://jsfiddle.net/Z4QDC/2/

Answer (score 1):

i would define some jquery to do this, and use a custom class.

```
//when the document is loaded, execute the following code
$(document).read(function(){

//on this elements hover, ...
$('.ugd_ele_normal').hover( function(){
    //we add the class black to the parent on hover
  $(this).parent().addClass("black");
},
function(){
   //and remove it on exit hover.
   $(this).parent().removeClass("black");
});
});
```

​
can be seen in action here:
http://jsfiddle.net/xBuyC/

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$('input[name="ugd_1"]').hover(function() {
    $(this).parent().css('background-color', 'COLOR');
});
```

Hope it helps.